# Opening HTTP content within HTTPS

Tags: firefox, https

We have a HTTPS website and I need to display a HTTP website (any external website) into my page. The website used iframe for displaying it. We realised that it doesn't work in mozilla firefox. We are getting a "mixed content" error. I am searching for an alternative to iframe now. I understand that it makes no sense to bypass the security warning. We also do not want to change any browser settings as it is possible that all the users may not have permissions to change browser settings. Using tags like `<embed>` or redirecting in `<div>` tag also gives the same problem.
Is there any way to do this in C# code and not using HTML and scripting.
Response.redirect() does not work in our application. I do not have a problem if the page is redirected but I prefer a dialog/popup window for the external website to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a security consideration. Your HTTPS site is not truly safe when using mixed content.

Use HTTPS for your external site, period.

As [Mozilla suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content):

> The best strategy to avoid mixed content blocking is to serve all the content as HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: I guess this is the only option I have. This was the only answer I found while I was searching for alternatives. :)
However, this is in our requirement so I need to search till I find a dead end.

Comment: Or simply present to whoever you report to that this is not what should be done.